# My android google Map v2 application crashes

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm making an android map application , using goggle maps v2 , alla went ok until i run the application , it crashs . thes are my files :

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.geo.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
        Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(KIEL)
            .title("Kiel")
            .snippet("Kiel is cool")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

        // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

        //    Zoom in, animating the camera.
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.geo.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.geo.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.geo.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB0MLq8L4YCA9GC05iD1V7OYfqlkUa0lhA" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**The application crashed , and i have this on my LogCat**

```
   04-10 10:59:02.545  11918-11918/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   04-10 10:59:02.545  11918-11918/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is OFF
   04-10 10:59:02.725  11918-11918/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ --- registering native functions ---
   04-10 10:59:03.495      104-205/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.geo.app/.MainActivity }
   04-10 10:59:03.605  11918-11918/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
   04-10 10:59:03.605  11918-11923/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
   04-10 10:59:03.625  11918-11926/? I/AndroidRuntime﹕ NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
   04-10 10:59:03.675    5325-5325/? D/PackageAddedReceiver﹕ package added com.geo.app
   04-10 10:59:03.695      104-107/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.geo.app for activity com.geo.app/.MainActivity: pid=11928 uid=10082 gids={3003, 1015}
   04-10 10:59:04.175      182-182/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 5596 objects / 283440 bytes in 5136ms
   04-10 10:59:04.275   3332-11910/? D/RegisterService﹕ insert plugin size 1
   04-10 10:59:04.335      104-243/? D/Sensors﹕ open_akm, fd=148
   04-10 10:59:04.625        77-77/? D/AK8973﹕ Compass Start
   04-10 10:59:04.745  11928-11928/com.geo.app W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 3704 (MapAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
   04-10 10:59:04.745  11928-11928/com.geo.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
   04-10 10:59:04.745  11928-11928/com.geo.app D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: dead code 0x0010-00ae in Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;.createFromAttributes (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMapOptions;
   04-10 10:59:04.755  11928-11928/com.geo.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
   04-10 10:59:04.755  11928-11928/com.geo.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028a00)
   04-10 10:59:04.775  11928-11928/com.geo.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
        at com.geo.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   04-10 10:59:04.845      104-244/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.geo.app/.MainActivity
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace.

Comment: you need to post the full stacktrace there is a caused by part which indicates the cause of app crash. You only posted a few lines

Comment: @Raghunandan : check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a meta tag in the manifest file

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You don't need these

```
<permission
android:name="com.geo.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

Also it is better to check the availability of google play services before intializing `GoogleMap` object

Edit:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

You haven't referenced google play services library project in your android map project.

Comment: that doesn't work ,in fact this line is highlithed with red on the manifest , which means that google play version was not found ! i'm checking my libs on the android studio , to see if i linked correctly them to the project

Comment: @wissem46 well it should. If not the library project isn't referenced properly. Secondly post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @wissem46 you haven't referenced google play services properly. Check the edit. Reference it properly and it will work

Comment: @wissem46 check this http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. the docs has steps for both eclipse and android studio

Comment: Thank you @Raghunandan , that was helpful so helpful , added to that i discovered in the documentation an important detail about the android version , i was running it on a v2.2 android device , that's why the application crashed. i moved to v4.4 and wow ! it works

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity.java class change the fragment import statement

`import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: The import is not need

Comment: @wissem46 there is no need for this import at all. you already have `import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;`